# Epplus Excel Library C#

Tags: c#, excel, oop, dispose, epplus

I want to know how to close the `ExcelPackage` (epplus)? I have searched about it everywhere, but all the epplus codes are written with `using` keyword.

*For example, once we open the file stream (fstream), we need to essentially close the file back. In Java, once we use `BufferedReader` or `Scanner` object, we need to close it with `.close()` or `.dispose()`.*

**Here is my purpose:** 
I want to implement a class that has attributes of `ExcelPackage` and `ExcelWorksheet` and some other methods and attributes. I am implementing a custom Excel Object using OOP technique so that I can use my custom Excel library to manipulate Excel files for my company.

My custom Excel Class has

 `constructor with a filename parameter`

`init() - initialize the ExcelPackage and store it in the attribute`,

`create() - for creating excel with our data`

`some methods for excel functionalities`

`save() - for saving the Excel File`

`close() - for closing the ExcelPackage` <= **I need to know how to dispose/close the excel package I instantiate with init() method**

Comment: Did you look at what the using statement does under the hood? That will tell you a lot about what you need to do for your app. And if you're going to make use of an IDisposable object as state (a field or property) in your class, then your class should also implement IDisposable.

Comment: I didn't think about it. I was expecting something simple like .close() method from EPPlus to close ExcelPackage. Then, if your answer is the only option, then I will implement IDisposable. Thank you for your advice, I will check using statement .

Comment: It's basically that simple. The using statement calls Dispose on the IDisposable object.

Comment: Note you could call `ExcelPackage.Dispose` described in the [documentation](https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.3/api/OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.html#OfficeOpenXml_ExcelPackage_Dispose) as "Closes the package." but that would not be best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `using` statement to automatically disposes of the object. [As msdn says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects#the-using-statement)

> The using statement in C# and the Using statement in Visual Basic
> simplify the code that you must write to cleanup an object. The using
> statement obtains one or more resources, executes the statements that
> you specify, and automatically disposes of the object. However, the
> using statement is useful only for objects that are used within the
> scope of the method in which they are constructed.

In addition, [ExcelPackage implements `IDisposable`](https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.3/api/OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.html):

```
public sealed class ExcelPackage : IDisposable
```

[An example of using:](https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.3/api/OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.html)

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(someNewFile))
```